# Hi, I have issue in my Volley post method

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I want to post the data as json formatted,but i dont know how to do that please help me to solve this issue.Normally i use the Volley post method as below (Its not any formatted type),its perfectly working for me,but now my backend developer ask me to post details as json format.

```
 String url=" http://10.10.4.27/teacherapp_dxb/index.php/teacher_app_cn/login?user_id=EMP263&password=thanzeel";
 StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            Log.d(TAG, "login Response: " + response.toString());
            hideDialog();

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
           }

                else {
                    // order error
                    String responseMsg = jObj.getString("response");
                    Toast.makeText(Viewactivity.this,
                      "ooola kirane"+ responseMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(Viewactivity.this,
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            hideDialog();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Post product to orderplacing url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
           params.put("user_id,"EMP263")
            params.put("password","thanzeel");

            return params;
        }

    };

    // Adding request to  queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq);
   }
```

In the above code i send the data wit out any format,but the backend developer need get the data as json format.So please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Since the response is a JSONObject, so I think you should you JsonObjectRequest instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like below in your `getParams()`

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("user_id","EMP263");
                    params.put("password","thanzeel");

            JSONObject jsonObjectParam = new JSONObject(params);

            Map<String,String > postParams = new HashMap<>();
            postParams.put("key",""+jsonObjectParam);
```

you can ask for this **"key"** to your backend team.

```
Hope it helps!
```

Comment: user_id,password are the key provided by them

Comment: then I think you were sending it in right way. if you post exact format how do you want it I can help more.@swaroop

Comment: actually they provided two key values for sending the data,they are user_id,password.the backend guy want recive these informations as json array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100747/discussion-between-swaroop-and-shishram).

Comment: did it fix your issue?

Comment: Nope Shishram,can you please give your email or anything for contacting

Comment: shishramkrwl@gmail.com, you can ping me on hangout

Comment: Thanks for your valuable help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send data in `JSONArray` from android app try this way :

```
 public String makeJSON(String s1,String s2,String s3){
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

        JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
        try {
            data.put("dataparam1",s1);
            data.put("dataparam2", s2);
            data.put("dataparam3", s3);


        } catch (JSONException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }

        jsonArray.put(data);

        JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonData.put("dataArray", jsonArray);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String jsonStr = jsonData.toString();
        System.out.println("jsonString: "+jsonStr);

        return jsonStr;
    }
```

And if you just want to send data in `JSONObject` try this :

```
public String createjson(String s1,String s2,String s3)
 {
  JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
  JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
          try {
                jsonObj.put("dataparam1",s1);
                 jsonObj.put("dataparam2",s2);
                 jsonObj.put("dataparam3",s3);
                 jsonArr.put(jsonObj);
                 jsonObject.put("cartItems", jsonArr);
            } catch (JSONException e) {}
            return jsonObject.toString(); 
            }
```

Comment: Hi if you dont mind  can you give me example using my above code